# Qui peut m'expliquer cette phrase ?

Tags: infinitif

> Selon les termes même de l'arrêt, ces droits acquis ne sont pas en danger, du fait qu'ils ne visent pas à protéger ce qu'ils estiment être déterminant dans la décision de renverser Roe : la protection d'une vie potentielle

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roe_v._Wade

Pourquoi l'auteur utilise « être » après le verbe « estimer » ?

Answer (score 1):

Ils estiment que c'est déterminant ==> c'est ce qu'ils estiment être déterminant

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Ce paragraphe parle des autres droits (**contraception, au mariage interracial et au mariage entre personnes de même sexe**) en disant que le traité qui vient d’être rendu ne met pas en danger ses droits : l’arrêt vise à **protéger une vie**; les autres droits ne concernent pas la protection d’une vie et les juges estiment qu’ils ne sont pas remis en cause par leur décision.